# Updating one sheet and having it carry over to another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that contains 2 sheets.

One is a master forms list and the other is a log for document control changes.

What I would like to have happen is, when I make a new entry into the Document change control log, look for the form number in the master list and then enter the DCN number, Rev level, and Date to match what I entered in the DCN log.

I have very little experience with formulas. Is this something that is possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it is, but the result done with formulas is volatile; if you change the master list, the value will change. Perhaps it is not something you will want to happen if you work with logs.